# How use dynamic routes to find people in my mongoose database with node.js

Tags: express, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
    app.get('/admin/reservas/:param', function(req, res) {
        var param = req.param("param");
        console.log(param);
        mongoose.model('Something').findOne(
            {
            id: param
            }, function(err, obj) {
                res.send(obj);
                console.log(obj);
            }
        );
    });
```

I have this route, and this EJS:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
  <td> <a href= <%="/admin/reservas/" + data[i].id  + ""%>><%= data[i].id   %></a></td>
  <td> <a href= <%="/admin/reservas/" + data[i].name    + ""%>><%= data[i].name     %></a></td>
<% } %>
```

And is fine, when i click in the id, i find what the id in the db that i want, but I want to be able to find by the name too.

So i was trying to change the routes:

```
    app.get('/names/:param', function(req, res) {
        var param = req.param("param");
        console.log(param);
        mongoose.model('Something').findOne(
            {
            id: param,
            name: param
            }, function(err, obj) {
                res.send(obj);
                console.log(obj);
            }
        );
    });
```

but is returning anything, both the id and the name

Comment: Not really sure what you are after here and some sample data might help explain more. But "id" and "name" properties are no likely to have the same value. Perhaps you are just looking for "name" and in copying the code you have not understood to remove "id" from the query. Not really seeing the point otherwise since "id" is required to be unique. Or do you mean "id" **or** "name", whichever matches?

Comment: i'm sorry, my english is not good... I want to be able to find a match in my db with the id or the name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB query arguments are by default always a logical **and** condition. In order to use a logical **or** there is the [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator:

```
    app.get('/admin/reservas/:param', function(req, res) {
        var param = req.param("param");
        console.log(param);
        mongoose.model('Something').findOne(
            {
                "$or": [
                    { id: param },
                    { name: param }
                ]
            }, function(err, obj) {
                res.send(obj);
                console.log(obj);
            }
        );
    });
```

The [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator takes an array of query documents to consider the conditions of. It is a "short circuit" match where the first condition to evaluate as `true` makes the statement true.

At least that would be true if not of a specific problem here. See `_id` and it's `id` alias is a special value to both MongoDB and Mongoose. By default this will try to "cast" to an `ObjectID` type but it cannot if the string supplied is invalid, such as "fred" for example.

This would cause an exception as the query arguments are supplied. So the bottom line rule is your cannot "mix types" in an **`$or`** condition in this way with something that would not survive the conversion from `String`. You would have to do it "logically" in a different way by testing the value 
for what it is:

```
    app.get('/admin/reservas/:param', function(req, res) {
        var param = req.param("param");
        console.log(param);

   var query = {};

       try {
           var id = mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(param);
           query = { "id": id };
       } catch {
           query = { "name": param };
       }

        mongoose.model('Something').findOne(
            query, function(err, obj) {
                res.send(obj);
                console.log(obj);
            }
        );
    });
```

That means that the query is now built in a way that mongoose will parse it considering the schema "types" to apply then there is no error since the decision of which field to query on was made elsewhere.

Alternately of course you can "bypass" the mongoose method behavior and just use the raw driver:

```
    app.get('/admin/reservas/:param', function(req, res) {
        var param = req.param("param");
        console.log(param);

        var id ="";

        try {
            id = mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(param);
        }

        mongoose.model('Something').collection.findOne(
            {
                "$or": [
                    { id: id },
                    { name: param }
                ]
            }, function(err, obj) {
                res.send(obj);
                console.log(obj);
            }
        );
    });
```

But of course you need to do the type conversion yourself and not only for "testing" otherwise even a correct "String" value representing an `ObjectID` would not work.

Comment: Strange, same effect.. i cant use the both, i only can find by the name if i take off the id.. i am coping your code..

Comment: @FátimaAlves Well yes and there is a reason that possibly deserves better explanation. And `ObjectId` type of field is a special case here and the code would fail trying to convert say, "fred" which would not be a valid `ObjectId` value. Would work with any another "String" field though.

Comment: you are right, look -> ErrorCastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "Fatima" at path "_id"

Comment: @FátimaAlves I added code to explain how to do it now. As I said the "type casting" is the problem in this case, but on two "string" fields a standard application of `$or` is normal.